# treeview web part for document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have tried bamboo, redsun and other existed WebPart, none of those supports sp online

My inquire is simple: how can I achieve such layout structure for left side menu, or where I could purchase or download such customized WebPart for sharepoint online

Main Folder

-- Sub Folder

-- Sub Folder

-- -- Document files

--Sub Folder

-- -- Sub Sub Folder

-- -- -- Document files

-- -- -- Document files

Main Folder 2

-- Sub Folder

...

...

I'm looking for a WebPart something like this one: www.codeproject.com/.../Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint

The only thing that WebPart is not working under SharePoint online...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could build it yourself based on the codeproject.com/Articles/37530/… post. The code's there, should be easy enough building a sandboxed solution based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SharePoint document library tree viewer that works very well, also has custom search box to search quickly for users, qipoint.com

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is a commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to show treeview control in the navigation is to enable treeview and disable quick launch. You can go to site settings-->treeview under look and feel to do this.

Comment: hi, tks for the reply, but your answer doesn't suit my question. please read my question, I need to show document files, like the sample web part i provided, but it doesn't support sp online

Comment: can u edit your sites using Sharepoint designer?

Comment: indeed, i'm using sp designer right now, but i couldn't find any datasource that sp online provides to get document library and its files. Liked I said, only document library folders is provided as datasource

Answer (score 0):

Below links may help you

http://davehunter.co.uk/2009/03/11/creating-a-tree-view-control-webpart/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/sharepoint/69/10330836/sharepoint-document-library-structure-bind-to-treeview-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look for Javascript based solutions like below:

http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/

https://www.jstree.com/demo/

Answer (score -1):

hala you can build one yourself if you are comfortable with jquery.
Search for jquery Treeview.You can use sharepoint designer.Grab the datasource and you are ready to go.
Hope that helps

or if you have the cash see this
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/p-38-tree-view-web-part.aspx

Comment: hi, tks for the reply, could you provide me a bit more detail about relative datasource or where I can get it? sp online is more restricted than sp, so many datasource is not accessible..
btw, liked i said, the bamboo or redsun web part only supports sp, not sp online